# How to pass table row data as props to another page using onClick event in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props, react-table

> I'm new to React Js and developing a delivery portal that needs to
> send table data onclickevent to another page. I'm still new to props
> and react REDUX and have no idea how to implement this. There are 3
> pages basically.
> 1.Home.js
> 2.Pending.js
> 3.Confirmed.js
>
> we use Spring boot for back end and mongoDB as database and Pending.js
> file retrieve data from database.What I want to do is pass table
> records to confirmed.js page user click on send to RTS button. I'm
> clueless on how to do that.
>
> Pending.js

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';


//import Orders from "../components/Orders";



function Pending(){

const [posts,setPosts]=useState([]);
const [deliveryAgent, setDeliveryAgent] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/list")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    setPosts(res.data)
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err)
})
},[])

   return (
      <div>
          <div>
            <NavBar/>
         
        </div>
       
            <div>
            <h3 className="text-left" style={{padding: "20px 0px"}}>Pending Orders</h3>
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead class="table-light">
                    <tr>
                        
                       <td>Order Id</td>
                        <td>Customer Id</td>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>Delivery Agent</td>
                        <td>Confirm Order</td>

                        
                       

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
               {
                 posts.map
                    (post=>(
                    <tr key={post.id}>
                    <td>{post.id}</td>
                    <td>{post.sellerId}</td>
                    <td>{post.address}</td>
                    <td> 
                    
      
 
  <div class="dropdown">

  <select class="form-select form-select-sm mb-1" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
  <option selected><strong> Delivery Agent</strong> </option>
  <option value="1">Agent A</option>
  <option value="2">Agent B</option>
  <option value="3">Agent C</option>
</select>
    
 
</div>
</td>



 <td><a href="/confirmed" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" role="button">Send to RTS</a> 
 </td>
 </tr>
  ))

          }
          </tbody>
          </table>
                      
        </div>
        </div>

      )
    }
    export default Pending;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use send data using routes please make sure you use react-router-dom version ^6.2.2

I have already implemented such scenario you can also refer my repo here https://github.com/amansadhwani/auto-logout-react/tree/main/src

import react-router-dom in your Pending component see below

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Initialize useNavigate

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

You should never use anchor tag (a) in reactjs instead use Link

replace this code where you are having button element

```
<td><button onClick={()=>navigateToConfirmed(post)}> Send to RTS </button></td>
```

now add this function navigateToConfirmed

```
const navigateToConfirmed= (post) =>{
        navigate(`/confirmed`, { state: post}); // here we will redirect user and send your data into state
     }
```

once you are redirected to confirmed component you need to extract your post which we sent earlier

import this

```
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
```

now to get your data

```
const {state} = useLocation();

console.log(state) // here you get your post data
```

Comment: This works fine but I want to get only the table row that user clicks on. Console shows all the data that I have on pending.js file. Is there a way that I can get only selected row to next page.

Comment: It only shows the required row on the console and I was wrong before. Can u please tell me how to display that state data on web page.

Comment: you can now render it like {state.address}

Comment: Thank you so much.. You saved my day.. I'm extremely grateful.. One last question.. Can you say in brief how I am supposed to keep track on the records that user already clicked confirmed. because when I go back and click on another record I can not see the previous record. Do I have to implement a function for that.

Comment: that depends on what you wish to do onclick of redirect you can update it in backend database